# Remove files in linux with different folder files to delete in a folder as particular folder

Tags: linux, command-line, filenames, rm

I want to remove multiple (all) files with different suffixes (`.log`,`.bin`) in a particular directory (`/home/username`) in a one-line command. How could I do that?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to delete all files of format '.log' and '.bin' in one command you can use:

```
rm *.bin *.log
```

and if you want a particular folder that different from your current path you can use:

```
rm /home/username/*.bin /home/username/*.log
```

Where `/home/username` is the particular folder.

This is what I understood from your question, if you meant something else please clarify.

Comment: i can only remove 7 days older files

Comment: This is not making any sense... `rm` supposed to remove files/dirs in any scenario except when you don't have the `w` permission to that directory... in my machine its working for files I just created. do you got any prompt?